# zypper list files in non-installed package

Tags: rpm, zypper

Using `zypper search`, I can find the package. I know that I could use

```
rpm -qlp <package.rpm>
```

to list the files, but I don't have it; since it is in one of the `zypper` repositories. Is there something like this?

```
zypper list-files-in <package>
```

**NOTE :** I am creating a [self-answered Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for other people trying to solve the same problem

Answer (score 6):

There does not seem to be an option in `zypper` to do this in one command, but you could:

Fetch the files without installing (Note: if this command threatens you to uninstall packages that is not a problem; with the `--download-only` flag `zypper` will stop after downloading)

```
zypper in --download-only <package>
```

Find the file:

```
find /var/cache/zypp -iname "package*rpm"
```

List the files in an uninstalled package:

```
rpm -qlp /var/cache/zypp/packages/<repo_alias>/suse/<arch>/<package-file-name>
```

Now you can clean up the files you downloaded (and some other cache) if you want:

```
zypper clean
```